# Qual é a função do código get_url_data()

Tags: php

Qual a função do código get_url_data()? o que ele faz? procurei no php.net e não encontrei nada, apenas sobre meta tag.

```
public function __construct () { 
 // Obtém os valores do controlador, ação e parâmetros da URL.
 // E configura as propriedades da classe.
 $this->get_url_data();
```

Comment: Não parece ser uma função nativa do PHP mesmo. Onde viu essa função? Ela lembra bastante o tipo de nomenclatura que o WordPress utiliza.

Comment: Na verdade ela aparece desta forma para mim.

public function __construct () {
 
 // Obtém os valores do controlador, ação e parâmetros da URL.
 // E configura as propriedades da classe.
 $this->get_url_data();

Comment: Ãhm, então não é uma função do PHP e sim um método desta classe que está lendo.

Comment: Há é verdade me desculpe não tinha me atentado a isso, por isso não encontrei em lugar nenhum, Obrigada.